# jquery mobile, event on page changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jqplot

I've got a very easy problem, but my knowledge about deeper JS is a bit too limited.
What I have created is a simple jQuery Mobile Application.

Page A has got an link element to page B. Page B holds some JavaScript, that fires jqPlot to draw an chart.

When I Access Page B directly, it works fine. When using the Link on Page A, it doesn't fire the JavaScript code.

Inside B I just Call the `$(document).ready(function (){});`

Can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `pagechange` event in the events documentation:
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

This event should accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry i solved it myself now. The Problem was, that i put the page events under the head of the new page (within script brackets). 

correct would be within the new "page" Tag, then the event will start working :-)

Comment: For some reasons `pagechange` was not helping however I fixed my problem with `pageshow`.